# creating a class that returns a b2Body issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, physics, box2d-iphone

I have to created a class that returns a b2Body, which I am trying to access in the HelloWorldLayer.mm file. See the circle class below:

the Circle.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "PhysicsSprite.h"

#define PTM_RATIO 32

@interface Circle : CCLayer   {

}

+(b2Body *)rCircle;

@end
```

and the Circle.mm

```
#import "Circle.h"

@implementation Circle


+(b2Body *)rCircle    {

//body and fixture defs for circleSprite
b2World *world_;
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.density = 0.1;
b2PolygonShape polygonShape;
fixtureDef.shape = &polygonShape;

PhysicsSprite* circleBodySprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"circleB.png"];
//[self addChild:circleBodySprite z:1];

//body with circle fixture
b2CircleShape circleShape;
circleShape.m_radius = circleBodySprite.contentSize.width/2 / PTM_RATIO;
fixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
b2Body* chainBase = world_->CreateBody( &bodyDef );
chainBase->CreateFixture( &fixtureDef );
[circleBodySprite setPhysicsBody:chainBase];


return chainBase;

}


@end
```

I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error pointing to the line:

```
    b2Body* chainBase = world_->CreateBody( &bodyDef );
```

I don't know what I've done wrong. I've also been accessing the `b2Body` in the HelloWorldLayer.mm in the following way:

```
[Circle rCircle];
```

Which also gives a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

I want the class to return a `b2Body` so I can create a joint in the HelloWorldLayer.mm.

Comment: Am I overlooking something or have you simply not created your `b2World`? `world_ = new b2World()`

Comment: I don't really understand why I've got to initialize the world as you stated. `world = new b2World(gravity);` I've already done that in the HelloWorldLayer.mm class. Wouldn't that be creating two world's? please explain. I just want my `rCircle` method to return a b2Body which I plan to use in the `HelloWorldLayer.mm` to create a joint with another body.

Comment: Unfortunately Objective-C is not my forté, so I don't completely follow it, but I don't see where you set your `world_` to be the one you created. Perhaps someone more versed in the language can help you with that, if that's the problem to begin with.

Comment: @wilM You need to pass the b2World that you create in HelloWorldLayer.mm to the Circle class by passing it as a function argument. Like: `[Circle rCircleUsingWorld:world_];`

Comment: @Lukman I don't really understand your comment. Could you explain further? Would rather adding a b2World parameter to the `rCircle` method do the job?

Comment: Why is addChild of the PhysicsSprite commented out? If you're not adding it to the scene there's no point in creating the PhysicsSprite in the first place.